# How to add tags to aws resources created by spring stream cloud with kinesis binder and kcl enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-kpl

I have spring cloud stream application with kinesis binder

The application can create resources on startup if not exists: kinesis streams, dynamodb tables for kcl

I would like that on creation of those resources i will be able to add custom tags to each of the resources , as if i would create them from console, cli or java sdk tools

is this possible ? How can I do that? some example will be great

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible at the moment.

If that is not so hard, we can consider some `ResourceConfigurer` abstraction to ask end-user to provide before calling creation for those resources.

Otherwise, please, really go ahead with AWS console to create those resources in advance.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt response , I think it will be a good idea to add something like this, but for now I will go with creating the resources externally